# Making AWS Lambda requests to Google Calendar API on behalf of a user (python)

Tags: reactjs, oauth, aws-lambda, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

Me and my team are trying to build a React web application that requires read/write access to the user's Google Calendar in order to provide some functionality.

I would like to use AWS Lambda functions (preferably written in python) to do this, but I'm struggling to understand how can I authenticate the lambda function to read/write the user's calendar.

I have been able to authenticate to my own calendar within a jupyter notebook using the `from_client_secret` method, but I don't think that could work in lambda:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json', scopes=scopes)
#credentials = flow.run_console()
```

I suspect I need to exchange something for a token that lambda can use every time it needs to access a particular user's calendar, but how would I go about implementing that?

The Google Server to Server documentation recommends the use of Service accounts, but struggling to see how I'd implement that in Lambda. Any help would be appreciated.